# Webscokets vs Server Side Events - NodeJS backend and VueJs client

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, long-polling

I have a front end client, which is written in VueJs and a Backend API which is written in Node Js. The Node API communicates with other third party APIs and in turn sent responses back to the client. Now for some of the APIs, it is taking a long time, more than a minute to complete the request and send the response back to the client. As the Node App is proxied over Akamai, it sends a 503 error after a certain time and thus and error will be thrown to the enduser. But the actual process that the third party API do is still in progress and it will send a success response back to the Node App once it is completed. As the client already received the error, it will not receive the success message.

I have this issue with the account creation flow. The client form data is posted to NodeJS backend, which eventually post to another third party API. While waiting for the call to finish, the Akamai proxy will send 503 HTTPS status with Zero Size object response. Client receives this error message and a custom error will be shown. But the account is being created in the backend and eventually it will send success response to the node app, but this never reaches the client and so the user. There is a chance that user will create another account.

The front end call is as follows:

```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const config = {}
    config.method = 'POST'
    config.url = APIaddress
    config.data = data
    config.params = params
    config.withCredentials = true
    config.httpsAgent = new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true })

    console.log('Config: ', config)

    axios(config).then(response => {
      console.log('RESPONSE: ', response)
      resolve(response)
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('ERROR: ', error.response)
      reject(error.response.data)
    })
  })
```

Here I added the `KeepAlive` option, but it has no effect and I still get the error.

Now, in the backend also, I use `agentkeepalive`, and the call is as follows:

```
      const HttpsAgent = agentkeepalive.HttpsAgent
      const keepaliveAgent = new HttpsAgent({
          timeout:120000,
          freeSocketTimeout:60000
      });
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: config.endpoint.url,
      headers:
        {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        },
      data: data,
      json: true,
        httpsAgent:keepaliveAgent
    };

    axios(options)
      .then(response => response.data)
      .then(response => {
        
        resolve(response)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
       
          logger.error({
            message: `Error while creating account: ${error}`
          });

        reject(error);
      });
```

Now in order to account for the delays, I am planning to use `Server Side Events` or `WebSockets`. I am very new to this and not sure which one to use. I think by using one of these, I can send response back to the client once the account is created. Currently the client is waiting for the account to be created, but I want to make it in such a way that client will send the initial requests and then the server will send notification to the client, once the account is created. This will avoid the unnecessary timeouts and other related issues.

I not sure which solution has to be used here. It will be helpful if someone can shed some light. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from SSE and RestAPI to WebSocket on my Node and React app. My setup is as follows:

Create WebSocket server in Node

Create connection from client to server

Then I use "publish-subscribe" pattern.
When client needs something from server, it sends WebSocket message to server with specific sign (In my case it is called "route".) Server filters the message and sends it to proper router (not the Express one, these are routes in my server handling the WebSocket requests.)
As it is processed, server sends WebSocket message back to client, which filters it and processes.

This allows me to have always opened connection to server, what is very swift, and - that's what you are looking for - wait for some message from server without blocking the connection or risking timeout.

Very simple code example:

```
server:
ws.on('message', m => {
   if (m.route === DO_SOMETHING) {
      ...do something...
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({route: DO_SOMETHING_RESPONSE}, message: 'Something was 
      done'})
   }
)

client:
// I want something to be done from server:

ws.send(JSON.stringify({route: DO_SOMETHING, message: 'something should be done'}))

// this is send and you can wait a year for a response, which is catched with:

ws.on('message', m => {
   if (m.route === DO_SOMETHING_RESPONSE) {
      console.log('Yupeee, something was done!')
   }
)
```

This way you can handle unlimited number of requests. You can make them independent as in this example. Or you can force client to wait for the answger from server.